# S3 / COS: rclone authentication using config for IBM Cloud fails

Tags: amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, rclone, cloud-object-storage

I am trying to use rclone utility for transfer from AWS S3 to IBM COS.

It works for AWS S3 but not sure why it fails for IBM COS.
Using the service credentials , API key as access key id and resource instance id as secret access key.

```
Rclone Config : 
[COS_SOURCE]
type = s3
location_constraint = us-standard
provider = IBMCOS
env_auth = false
access_key_id = xxx
secret_access_key = xxxx
endpoint = s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
```

This fails tried with different user keys and service ids.
Error which I get when I run rclone lsd COS_SOURCE:

```
2021/05/17 18:17:25 DEBUG : Using config file from "/Users/deepali.mittal/.config/rclone/rclone.conf"
2021/05/17 18:17:25 DEBUG : rclone: Version "v1.55.1" starting with parameters ["rclone" "lsd" "COS_SOURCE:" "-vvvv"]
2021/05/17 18:17:25 DEBUG : Creating backend with remote "COS_SOURCE:"
2021/05/17 18:17:27 ERROR : : error listing: InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key ID you provided does not exist in our records.
    status code: 403, request id: 1425c482-b423-4cb9-a01d-f3566a385f3d, host id: 
2021/05/17 18:17:27 DEBUG : 6 go routines active
2021/05/17 18:17:27 Failed to lsd with 2 errors: last error was: InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key ID you provided does not exist in our records.
    status code: 403, request id: 1425c482-b423-4cb9-a01d-f3566a385f3d, host id:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use HMAC credentials. You can generate them together with the regular IBM Cloud IAM credentials for that service.

Comment: Thanks .. It worked. I was trying to figure out from where do we get these credentials. And got this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=analytics-determining-access-key-id-secret-access-key  which is incorrect.